# Custom discreet Slider - Problem in aligning the thumb to the division's center

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-layout

Wanted to create a custom discreet slider as shown below:

[image: here].

For that, created 2 custom class. For thumbShape: subclassed from SliderComponentShape and for tickMarkShape: subclassed from SliderTickMarkShape.

In both the class, I was just fiddling around the paint object and radius to create the custom shape for my division and my thumb.

In the SliderComponentShape (thumbShape) subclass, I just changed the radius to 20% of its passed size while drawing the circle on the canvas as below.

```
canvas.drawCircle(center, (radiusTween.evaluate(enableAnimation) * 0.20), Paint()..color = colorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation))
```

And in the SliderTickMarkShape (tickMarkShape) subclass, I modified the paint object, and changed its style and strokeWidth like so.

```
final Paint strokePaint = Paint()
      ..color = ColorTween(begin: begin, end: end).evaluate(enableAnimation)
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    if (tickMarkRadius > 0) {
      context.canvas.drawCircle(center, tickMarkRadius, strokePaint);
    }
```

This gives the desired result only when the thumb is placed in the center of the slider.
That is, the small circle (the slider's thumb) fits to the center of the ring like design of the divisions, only when the thumb is in the center of the slider.
If it is dragged to other places it's not properly aligned.
I tried to fiddle with the thumb's center.dx value. but that change works only to one of the divisions and rest gets unaligned.

[image]
[image]

Any Help on how to fix the thumb to the center of the division in all the values?

**EDIT - Code Included:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DonutSliderThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  const DonutSliderThumbShape({
    this.enabledThumbRadius = 10.0,
    this.disabledThumbRadius,
  });

  final double enabledThumbRadius;

  final double disabledThumbRadius;
  double get _disabledThumbRadius => disabledThumbRadius ?? enabledThumbRadius;

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size.fromRadius(
        isEnabled == true ? enabledThumbRadius : _disabledThumbRadius);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    @required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    bool isDiscrete,
    TextPainter labelPainter,
    RenderBox parentBox,
    @required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    TextDirection textDirection,
    double value,
  }) {
    assert(context != null);
    assert(center != null);
    assert(enableAnimation != null);
    assert(sliderTheme != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.disabledThumbColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.thumbColor != null);

    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    final Tween<double> radiusTween = Tween<double>(
      begin: _disabledThumbRadius,
      end: enabledThumbRadius,
    );
    final ColorTween colorTween = ColorTween(
      begin: sliderTheme.disabledThumbColor,
      end: sliderTheme.thumbColor,
    );

    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = colorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawCircle(
        center, (radiusTween.evaluate(enableAnimation) * 0.20), paint);
  }
}
```

```
class DonutSliderTickMarkShape extends SliderTickMarkShape {

  const DonutSliderTickMarkShape({this.tickMarkRadius});

  final double tickMarkRadius;

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize({
    @required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
  }) {
    assert(sliderTheme != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.trackHeight != null);
    assert(isEnabled != null);
    return Size.fromRadius(tickMarkRadius ?? sliderTheme.trackHeight / 2);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    @required RenderBox parentBox,
    @required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    @required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    @required TextDirection textDirection,
    @required Offset thumbCenter,
    bool isEnabled = false,
  }) {
    assert(context != null);
    assert(center != null);
    assert(parentBox != null);
    assert(sliderTheme != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.disabledActiveTickMarkColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTickMarkColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.activeTickMarkColor != null);
    assert(sliderTheme.inactiveTickMarkColor != null);
    assert(enableAnimation != null);
    assert(textDirection != null);
    assert(thumbCenter != null);
    assert(isEnabled != null);

    Color begin;
    Color end;
    switch (textDirection) {
      case TextDirection.ltr:
        final bool isTickMarkRightOfThumb = center.dx > thumbCenter.dx;
        begin = isTickMarkRightOfThumb
            ? sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTickMarkColor
            : sliderTheme.disabledActiveTickMarkColor;
        end = isTickMarkRightOfThumb
            ? sliderTheme.inactiveTickMarkColor
            : sliderTheme.activeTickMarkColor;
        break;
      case TextDirection.rtl:
        final bool isTickMarkLeftOfThumb = center.dx < thumbCenter.dx;
        begin = isTickMarkLeftOfThumb
            ? sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTickMarkColor
            : sliderTheme.disabledActiveTickMarkColor;
        end = isTickMarkLeftOfThumb
            ? sliderTheme.inactiveTickMarkColor
            : sliderTheme.activeTickMarkColor;
        break;
    }

    final double tickMarkRadius = getPreferredSize(
          isEnabled: isEnabled,
          sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
        ).width /
        2;
    final Paint strokePaint = Paint()
      ..color = ColorTween(begin: begin, end: end).evaluate(enableAnimation)
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    if (tickMarkRadius > 0) {
      context.canvas.drawCircle(center, tickMarkRadius, strokePaint);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: post your both shape's code

Comment: @pskink - Included the shape's code.

Comment: @venkat i have the same issue, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @VinceLowe - Sorry for the delay in reply.  No update on this. The issue is still open in flutter - [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62567)